# Folder Redirection - Explorer requires manual refresh

Tags: windows, dfs, windows-explorer, folder-redirection

When a user's My Documents folder is redirected to a DFS share, Windows Explorer requires a manual refresh after creating a new folder, file, etc. Interestingly, the manual refresh is not necessary when making a new briefcase.

I have tried a number of MS knowledge base articles, a hot-fix and a registry change, all with no success. In particular, I have tried [KB823291](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=823291) and [KB873392](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/873392).

The problem only occurs when going through the My Documents icon.  If I map a home drive for the user to the exact same location, e.g. `H:\DFS\user\documents`, open that drive and make new folders, then there is no problem.

Mapping My Documents to `H:\` also resolves the issue. However, as we need folder sync and people logging on off site with cached profiles, this is not a workable solution, as H: will not map and there will be no access to their docs.

Has anyone managed to figure a fix for this?

Comment: I am experiencing this issue as well, with Server 2008 and DFS shares. If accessing the UNC directly the refresh happens automatically. However, if my users use their shortcuts on the desktop, folders being viewed require a manual refresh. At first I thought this was an issue with the individual computer, but now it's happening to all 3 computers that access this DFS share. We've found no resolution yet.